# cannot await 'system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbsqlquery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1 and am getting the above subject line error. The design time compile error is on the second line starting with the await.

**How come I cannot await the SqlQuery?** If I remove the await, the clause is fine.

I have the below code snippets:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<HH_FuelTkt_Output>> GetFilteredFuelTicketsAsync(HH_FuelTkt_Input value)

var fto = await DbContext.HH_FuelTkt.SqlQuery("SELECT * from HH");
```

Comment: How do you consume `fto`?  (that's where you'd be applying the async mechanics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlQuery()` doesn't return a `Task`, so you can't await it.

[`SqlQuery.ToListAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn176851%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), however, does return a `Task` and can be awaited.

Comment: If I include SQL inside the SqlQuery, is it pre-compiled after it executes once like a stored procedure?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that one, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

[`DbSet.SqlQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) does not return a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and is thus not awaitable.